# jaspersoft print specific records from csv file

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Label set up in Jaspersoft Studio that references a data adapter file in CSV format.  The csv file contains thousands of records.  I want the end user to be able to select or key enter the "order no" for the specific records to print.  If one order no is entered - record is found and printed.  If ten order no's are entered - 10 records will print.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Parameters to let user make input. But because CSV is not query language, you can use Field Expression in Data Source

Here's how to add Parameter

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-parameters

And this is how to use Field Expression

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-apply-parameters-csv-data-source

<del>Detail:</del> **Filter by attribute:**

In query dialog, you select Filter Expression tab and fill the field with code like this

```
$F{order_no}.equals($P{order_no})
```

This code will filter the csv row that has **order_no field** that equal to **order_no parameters**

**Filter by multiple order_no:**

JasperReport are allowed user to do some scripting in Java or Groovy (depending or their settings). So you can do more complicated task like split input into array and use it to search rows.

What I have in mind, are ask end user to seperate order_no by space and use this script to filter the data.

```
Arrays.asList($P{order_no}.split(" ")).indexOf($F{order_no}) > -1
```

I have not tested this code yet, but hopefully you get the idea. (Experiment with the script).

Comment: How this information can help to filter data from *csv* datasource?

Comment: I adding examples to filter the code, does this explain how to filter data from csv datasource?

Comment: `If one order no is entered - record is found and printed. If ten order no's are entered - 10 records will print.` - No, it does not help for original question. The filter should limit number of records, not the filter by attribute

Comment: I think I understand the concept here.  I will test.

Comment: Tested the script.  It will display the Parameter order_no and can enter records to print.  But it ignores the filter and prints ALL records.  Will not print just the records I have entered.

Comment: The filter from datasource is ignored.  No Parameter prompting when I preview report.  Not respecting parameter - coming up as query expression - not filter expression.